# Jquery.Ajax not working with contentType:application/json

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have got this simple ajax request. The problem is the contentType. When I put this attribute, stuff gets sent but I cannot access it server-side. When I remove it, it gets sent fine (but presumably not in JSON) and I can access it as well. I was just wondering if someone can help me figure out the problem.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: _common.Ajax.url,
    data: {
        action: 'faraz'
    },
    contentType: "application/json"
})
    .success(function () {
    alert('success');
})
    .fail(function () {
    alert('failed');
})
    .error(function () {
    alert('errror');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will only format [`data` for the default of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Data to be sent to the server. **It is converted to a query string**, if not already a string. [...]

When a different `contentType` is desired, you have to also format `data` to match:

```
// ...
    data: JSON.stringify( { action: 'faraz' } ),
    contentType: "application/json"
// ...
```

Note: For ECMAScript 3, IE8, etc. support, you can include a polyfill like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).